# not able to copy excel column values to specified range in another excel file

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have written a small code to copy few columns from source excel file to another excel file (destination excel file) using c#. Below is sample image of source excel file.

[image]

The expected result in destination excel file should be as shown in below image.
[image]

Below is my code

```
    string fileTarget = @"C:\Users\sia\Desktop\Excel Automation\destination.xlsx";
    string fileTemplate = @"C:\Users\sia\Desktop\Excel Automation\source.xlsx";  

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbTemp, wbTarget;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sh;         


Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbSource = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileTemplate, ReadOnly: false);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet WorksheetSource = wbSource.Sheets[1];
    //Copy all range in this worksheet
    WorksheetSource.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);


    //Open destination workbook
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbDestination = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileTarget, ReadOnly: false);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet WorksheetDestination = wbDestination.Sheets[1];
    WorksheetDestination.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    wbDestination.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\sia\Desktop\Excel Automation\destination.xlsx");
    wbSource.Close();
    excel.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
```

But the i'm not getting the expected format, below is the result I'm getting.
[image]

where and what modification i need to do in my existing code to get the expected result.

Thanks

Comment: @ashleedawg  - edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify proper column and range, otherwise by default paste will go in the first column

```
workSheet.Range
```

For reference: [Copy/paste cells in Excel with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294597/copy-paste-cells-in-excel-with-c-sharp)